# how to copy data over with attachments to a new list

Tags: list, attachments, copy-item

I just created a new list by copying my template over so all of the columns have the same property... how can i filter on Area =NY and copy that data over included any attachments assoicated with the records over to my new list?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create your filtered view on your source list.

Then go to Site Settings and click on Content and Structure. This will take you to a screen with a hierarchy of your site.

Click on your source list and switch to your view.

Select the items you want, and in the ribbon select from the Actions drop down Copy (or Move, I'd suggest Copy to make sure things move over properly and when you've proofed it, use Move).

This will pop up a window asking you where the items should go. Select or destination and click OK and it will start to Copy (or Move) the items.

When done, do a comparison and make sure everything comes over correctly and with the attachments.