# Sharepoint Online Moving a large document library from one site to another

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-template, send-to-destination

I want to copy/move a large document library of over 100,000 documents items in around 3000 document sets, from one site to another. The sites are within the same Sharepoint: name.sharepoint.com but the document libraries are not within the same site.

I want to use one of these 3 options:

1) Create a Document Library as a template without content and move the thousands of documents from the initial library to the new one using the 'Send To' option. The problem with this is that it only works 1 item at a time, and since there are thousands of documents, this is not an option.

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnNz3.jpg)

2) Create a Document Library as a template including the content. The problem with this is the option that includes content is grayed out.

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW5Tf.jpg)

3) From the Office 365 Admin Panel - Sharepoint Admin Centre in the records management section, you can define a 'Send to connection'. So I created a new one called it 'Invoices' and selected the action as 'Copy'. I obtained the destination link from the Content Organizer Settings of the new site, which looks like this:

name.sharepoint.com/sites/DocumentManagement/_vti_bin/OfficialFile.asmx

When going in one of the document sets that I want to move and trying to copy an item using this new 'Send to Connection', I am getting this error: 'was not configured as a publication location for this location'

What should I look for in any of the options? I don't mind which one to use, though the second one would seem neater. Also, I wouldn't mind being directed into any type of code or workflow method that can achieve this, if Sharepoint doesn't already offer such functionality.

Comment: Are the libraries in the same site collection?

Comment: Yes they are, and it let me Send to with one document at a time.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest using Content and Structure in Site Settings to move or copy the files from one location to another.

Comment: How would this go about? Do you have a link I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

Since the source and destination are in the same site collection, you can use the Content and Structure option in Site Settings to copy or move files from one library to another.

The process is pretty simple, go to Site Settings where your destination library resides and go to COntent and Structure. Select the files you want and either select Copy to essentially duplicate the data or Move to shift it from one library to the other. Then a popup will ask you where you want to put the files. It will then perform the operation to move or copy the files.

You can do up to 1000 files at a time this way.

Similar: [how to copy data over with attachments to a new list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184858/how-to-copy-data-over-with-attachments-to-a-new-list/184864#184864)

Comment: Is there any option for a document library of 100,000 documents or more!?

Comment: I did about 150k that way in batches. You could also look at migration tools or writing something in PowerShell/CSOM.

Comment: Eric, excuse me I must have misunderstood. They are not document libraries on the same site collection, they are document libraries, on different sites, residing on the same Sharepoint. To explain: the original site is name.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Home.aspx and the original document library is there. The new document library is on a different site: name.sharepoint.com/sites/documentmanagent. Excuse me, Im a beginner in Sharepoint and I thought name.sharepoint.com is the Site Collection. In fact when trying with this method I cant see Site A from Site B and vice versa

Comment: I also edited the question with a clarification regarding your question (at the beginning), and added another option that I tried